# What is considered a good research record for an assistant professor job (tenure-track)?

Tags: publications, united-states, tenure-track

I'm a tenure-track professor in Brazil (and will receive tenure next year). However, I'm currently applying for some tenure-track jobs in USA.

Currently, I'm developing my statements (research, teaching, etc.) and writing down my CV. However, I don't have experience and don't know many PhD and PostDoc researchers from the USA to compare my research record with theirs.

**My question is**: what is considered a good research record for the selection committees in the USA? How many papers, number of citations, etc? What do these committees highly value?

I believe that I'm a little anxious regarding the selection process. Thus, I believe that evaluating my own research record with that of others will give me some peace of mind.

---

P.S.: I want to consider two fields: Computer Science and Industrial Engineering, as I have expertise in both (my lines of research encompasses operations research, machine learning, data science, theoretical computer science, and algorithms).

Comment: I'd look at the profiles of people recently hired in your field (basically any assistant professor would do): it's common for their full CVs to be on an academic web page. Every person evaluates differently so no specific record will guarantee or prevent a hire.

Comment: There are too many variables to give any valuable answer. An what would you do with an answer in any case? Your record is what it is. Apply to places that ask for things you are qualified for and note that tenure track positions are very hard to get and very competitive.

Comment: @BryanKrause I will try this

Comment: @Buffy is all about my anxious mind. I want to know my chances (if possible)

Comment: Your chances are what they are. Make a good application, get good letters of recommendation if that is required. Match your skills to the job. Good luck.

Comment: Institutions vary a lot too. Tier 1 research level is going to be hard to get even with a high quality record. Going down to lower tier institutions increases everyone's chances. Generally, the hiring process is very subjective and random too with so many working parts. Best idea is to cater each application as much as possible. Know your audience.